# R- create temporary table in sql server from R data frame

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, rodbc

I know I can create a temporary table in SQL from R with, for example:

```
require(RODBC)

X<- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};
    server=s001000;database=X1;trusted_connection=true')

sqlQuery(X, "create table #temptable (test int)" )
sqlQuery(X,  "insert into #temptable(test) values(201508)")
doesItWork <- sqlQuery(X, "select * from #temptable")
```

But I would like to create a temporary table in sql server from an R object (I have a table that has the result of previous R calculations and I need to query it against another table in SQL. I don't want to export it as txt and upload it to SQL server. It has to be a way to do it from R. I tried:

```
tabla<-data.frame(per=c(201508,201510))
sqlQuery(X, "Select * into ##temporal from tabla")
```

But I got an error message:

> "42S02 208 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid
>   object name 'tabla'." 
>    "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect
>    'Select * into ##temporal from tabla '"

I also know I can create a table with sqlSave:

```
sqlSave(X, tabla, rownames=FALSE,safer=FALSE)
```

But I want to create a **temporary** table.
How can I create a temporary table in SQL from an R object?

Comment: I don't think you can reference objects from your R session (`tabla`) within a query via `sqlQuery` as you can with, e.g. `sqldf`. Try using `sqlSave` or `sqlUpdate` for your insert operation.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I don't recall `sqlSave(conection, new_data, table_name, append = TRUE)` ever working correctly for inserting data into existing tables (e.g. *not* creating new tables), so you may have to use the less efficient approach of generating the `INSERT` statements yourself. For example,

```
con <- odbcConnect(...)

query <- "
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF ( OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##tmp_table') IS NOT NULL )
    DROP TABLE ##tmp_table;
CREATE TABLE ##tmp_table
    (
     [ID] INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
    ,[Value] DECIMAL(9, 2)
    );

SET NOCOUNT OFF;

SELECT  1;
"
sqlQuery(con, gsub("\\s|\\t", " ", query))


df <- data.frame(Value = round(rnorm(5), 2))

update_query <- paste0(
    "SET NOCOUNT ON; INSERT INTO ##tmp_table ([Value]) VALUES ",
    paste0(sprintf("(%.2f)", df$Value), collapse = ", "),
    " SET NOCOUNT OFF; SELECT * FROM ##tmp_table;"
)

sqlQuery(con, update_query)
#   ID Value
# 1  1  0.79
# 2  2 -2.23
# 3  3  0.13
# 4  4  0.07
# 5  5  0.50

#sqlQuery(con, "DROP TABLE ##tmp_table;")
#odbcClose(con)
```