# RODBC sqlSave can not append, Access column name with white space

Tags: r, append, rodbc

I can not append data frame into the an existing table, because the table in access has white space. 
e.g.

- Access table variable name: Dlr Name
- data frame variable name: DlrName

I try to replicate access table variable name to my df using varTypes=varTypes, but when I run the following code

```
sqlSave(access, Contracts_CurrMth, "T_Contracts", append=TRUE, rownames=FALSE, fast=FALSE, safer=TRUE, verbose=TRUE)
```

Looks like R automatically delete the space in my df variable name and The error msg is

> HYS22 -1507 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] The INSERT INTO statement contains the following unknown field name: DlrName

---

Anyone can help me on this please?

Some more background info:

R 32bit, access 2010, 32bit, both data table are same format
my data frame table is like this [data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9z0pw.jpg)

my access table is like this [access table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6awjb.jpg)

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37240553/unable-to-append-to-sql-server-table-using-sqlsave-in-r. The (unaccepted) answer there points the finger at column names and data types.

Comment: just edit my post, looks like it is related to the name space. I believe they are not the same problem. But thank you very much for your help!